# How to choose between .Include and .Join to get data from two tables in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-6.0

I have two tables (`Exception_T` and `SupplierByException_T`) and I want to get desired result from both of them based on the relationship. I have criteria where base query will be with one filter *but* I do have optional filters which I want to add on top of the query if they are available.

FYI, these table names were already defined, and I do not have control over it ATM.

**Desired Outcome:**

- Create a base query with one filter between two tables. (Could be .join or .include, whatever gives the result).
- Update this base query with where clause if optional filters are present.

I am trying `.Include` and `.Join` but I am not getting desired result.

**Option #1:** using `.Include`.

Here, let's say if `Exception_T` has one record and suppliers does not have records then instead of 0, it still pulls 1 record which is present in `Exception_T`.

```
var query = _dbContext.Exception
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .Include(x => x.Suppliers)
                      .Where(_ => _.Location.Equals(location));
```

**Option #2:** using `.Join`

This has two issues where a) one is common as above, b) I get duplicate records. Meaning, if I see same records repeated 2 times. So if I have 2 records then this will return 4. I am sure I am not leveraging `.Join` correctly here.

```
var query = from exc in _dbContext.Exception.AsNoTracking()
            join sup in _dbContext.SupplierByException.AsNoTracking() 
                 on exc.ExceptionId equals sup.ExceptionId
            where exc.Location.Equals(location)
            select exc;
```

**Option #3:** using `Linq` with `.GroupBy`.

This throws the following exception

```
var query = _dbContext.Exception.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.Suppliers)
            .Where(x => x.Location.Equals(location))
            .GroupBy(x => x.StockNumber)
            .ToList();
```

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Include(x => x.Suppliers)
> .Where(x => x.Location.Equals(__location_0))
> .GroupBy(x => x.StockNumber)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Here is the full code.

SQL Entities:

```
public class Exception 
{
    [Key]
    public int ExceptionId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(10), Unicode(false)]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long StockNumber { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(17), Column(TypeName = "char(17)")]
    public string Vin { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCarliCost { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCostSubmitted { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EarliestPaymentDate { get; set; }
    public bool? HasPartLineItems { get; set; }
    public bool? HasSubletItems { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<SupplierByException> Suppliers { get; set; }
}

public class SupplierByException 
{
    [Key] 
    public int SupplierByExceptionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long StockNumber { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(500), Unicode(false)]
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public bool? TiedToPart { get; set; }
    public bool? TiedToSublet { get; set; }
    public int ExceptionId { get; set; }
}
```

Repo.cs:

```
private IQueryable<Exception> GenerateBaseQuery(string location, string stockNumber = "", string exceptionType = "", string supplierName = "")
{
    // // Option-1
    // var query = _dbContext.Exception.AsNoTracking()
    //     .Include(x => x.Suppliers)
    //     .Where(_ => _.Location.Equals(location));
    
    // // Option-2
    // var query = from exc in _dbContext.Exception.AsNoTracking()
    //     join sup in _dbContext.SupplierByException.AsNoTracking() 
    //         on exc.ExceptionId equals sup.ExceptionId
    //     where exc.Location.Equals(location)
    //     select exc;
    // // query = query.Include(x => x.Suppliers);
    
    // Once above base query is created, using optional where clauses like below.
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stockNumber))
    {
        var convertedStockNumber = long.Parse(stockNumber);
        query = query.Where(e => e.StockNumber.Equals(convertedStockNumber));
    }
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exceptionType))
    {
        if (exceptionType.ToLowerInvariant()
            .Equals(ExceptionTypeConstants.ExceptionType.Parts.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            query = query.Where(e => e.HasPartLineItems.Equals(true));
        }
        
        if (exceptionType.ToLowerInvariant()
            .Equals(ExceptionTypeConstants.ExceptionType.Sublets.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            query = query.Where(e => e.HasSubletItems.Equals(true));
        }
        
        if (exceptionType.ToLowerInvariant()
            .Equals(ExceptionTypeConstants.ExceptionType.All.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            query = query.Where(e => e.HasPartLineItems.Equals(true) || e.HasSubletItems.Equals(true));
        }
    }
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(supplierName))
    {
        query = query.Include(o => o.Suppliers.Where(s => s.SupplierName == supplierName));
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: @Dai could you please provide an example with my snippet? I am trying diff approaches between `.include` and `.join` but not getting desired result. My very option#1, I have used `.include` but it is not giving me desired result as I've mentioned overthere.

Comment: You're getting duplicates because you're using `AsNoTracking` - you _should not_ normally use `AsNoTracking` unless you absolutely know otherwise: object-tracking is how EF filters out duplicates. It's like asking why your head hurts because you're intentionally wearing a hat that's too small...

Comment: I get duplicate records even if I remove `AsNoTracking` from my `Option #2`

Comment: Is the relationship between the tables 1-to-many? If so, then a `JOIN` betweeen the two will _necessarily_ give you duplicates of the principal table - that's what `JOIN` means... If you're trying to load an object-graph (i.e. the set of `Exception` objects *and* their set of dependent `SupplierByException` objects) then don't use a `JOIN` - use two queries in a batch (if your EFCore is configured to support it) - or use `Include` _on the dependent, not principal_ entity) _without_ `AsNoTracking` - that way EF will issue a single query with a `JOIN` and it will filter it out for you.

Comment: Also, **just don't** name a class "`Exception`" - that's just asking for trouble...

Comment: Though the generated sql would be overly complicated; `.Where(x => x.Suppliers.Any()).Include(x => x.Suppliers)`.

Comment: I do not understand from question why you need join and why you need Include. Please improve your question with more details.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have updated question. Hopefully, this will give clear idea.

Comment: @Dai These table names were already created, and I do not have liberty to change the names. I understand your point though, which is valid. Yes, I do have 1:N relationship and your assumption is correct.  I have added my config in quetion. Could you please provide an example when you say `use Include on the dependent, not principal entity) without AsNoTracking`

Comment: I still do not understand. What is wrong with first option? And `Include` is not for filtering but for loading related entities.

Comment: So let's say `Exception_T` has one record and `SupplierByException_T` has none, then option 1 will return `Exception` object with Supplier as an empty array. Here, the goal is, if supplier is an empty array then don't even get `Exception` object.

Comment: @GThree You can rename the C# `class` without renaming the table. Same goes for columns and other object-names. (How else do you think EF works with databases where table is named the same as a language keyword?). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#table-name

Comment: Just add filter `.Where(x => x.Suppliers.Any())`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv In this case, if I apply some random value for supplier, then it is still pulling records with `supplier` as empty array. Maybe I am understanding this correctly, OR I have not written my optional filters correctly.

Comment: Probably. `Include` is not filter, but you have to combine `Where` and `Include`: `query = query.Include(o => o.Suppliers.Where(s => s.SupplierName == supplierName)).Where(o => o.Suppliers.Any(s => s.SupplierName == supplierName));` `Include` is needed when you want to load Suppliers, otherwise it can be removed.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you so much for providing these 2 suggestions. Looks like it is giving me desired results. Let me play with this to cover all my scenarios. I'll update this thread once my tests are done.